# La mejor forma de meter datos de diferente tipo a una lista

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java (vengo de PHP), y me encuentro con que este lenguaje tiene un tipado muy muy fuerte y ando con el siguiente problema: quiero armar un array/lista que contenga datos de diferente tipo. Y hasta donde me entero, ¡esto no es posible!

Si hago una consulta a una base de datos, naturalmente voy a recuperar información de diferente tipo: el *id* es un int, el *nombre* un bool, la *fecha* un date, etc. ¿Cómo hago para meter esos datos en un array/lista si no son del mismo tipo?

Lo único que se me ocurre es lo siguiente, y la verdad dudo mucho que sea la mejor forma de hacerlo, ya que parece bastante sucio y poco elegante convertir todos los datos al mismo tipo, para que todo funcione:

```
int numero;
numero = 7;

String numeroBIS = String.valueOf(numero);

List<String> listaSoloString = new LinkedList<String>();
listaSoloString.add("Sólo");
listaSoloString.add("hay");
listaSoloString.add("cadenas");
listaSoloString.add("aquí");
listaSoloString.add(numeroBIS);

System.out.println(listaSoloString);
```

Comment: Por tu pregunta parece que no conoces el concepto de Clase

Comment: Muchas gracias, @pablo, tu comentario es de mucha ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la lista va ser de diferentes tipos entonces no le definas un tipo en particular.

```
List listaDeObjetos = new LinkedList();
```

Que sería equivalente a :

```
List<Object> listaDeObjetos = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

A esta lista le puedes agregar cualquier tipo:

```
listaDeObjetos.add(new Integer(8));
listaDeObjetos.add(new java.util.Date());
listaDeObjetos.add("casa");
listaDeObjetos.add("perro");
```

Ahora que esta lista te dará objetos y los tendrás que convertir.

```
Integer entero = (Integer)listaDeObjetos.get(0);
java.util.Date fecha = (java.util.Date)listaDeObjectos(1);
String cadena = (String)listaDeObjetos.get(2);

//etc.
```

Comment: Excelente, @AlbertoLopez. Respuestas como las tuyas son justo la información que un principiante necesita cuando se sumerge en un nuevo lenguaje. Es decir, explicaciones con _palitos y manzanas_. Gracias!